# How can I delete a Jabber account I created years ago?

Tags: icloud

When I first got my iMac about four years or so ago, I created a Jabber account for messaging, however I never used it. The email I used to sign up I now wish to associate with my iCloud account, however when I try to do so, it throws an error saying that this email is in use. Jabber is the only place I used that email address.

So is there a way for me to free that email address from the Jabber system so I can associate it on my iCloud?

**EDIT**:

The email address I wish to use is my custom Gmail address (email @ my domain), when I look in the messaging accounts section it seems this email address is linked to Google Talk which is inactive and has an account type of Jabber.

Comment: That message normally means that the email address is already associated with the application (iCloud), not that it's in use somewhere else.

Comment: Already done the basic checks, it isn't an iCloud account. I remember setting it up for Jabber and that's all @fixer1234

Comment: It looks like iCloud does some stuff "for your convenience", linking existing IM accounts from a range of services, including Jabber, to save you the setup.  That may be the source of the problem; it may not be an off-the-wall, unconnected event.  No idea how to solve it though.

Comment: That's what I thought, how annoying